# I want to Create textbox which allows only numbers. How can I do that with Typescript in aurelia?

Tags: typescript, textbox, aurelia

I want to enter only numbers in textbox so i have added oninput but i want to create using bindableproperty. I don't have idea how to do that. Please suggest me ?

## textbox.html

```
<template bindable="">
  <input style="
         box-sizing: border-box;"
         maxlength="10" ;
         oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
</template>;
```

## textbox.ts

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';
export class textbox {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

## app.html

```
<template bindable="">
  <require from="./components/textbox.html"></require>
  <textbox></textbox>
</template>
```

## app.ts

```
export class App {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I am just giving the idea, might be helpful:

In Html you may use  
(keyup)="methodName($event.targer.value)"  event.


In you ts file you may use:
bindedTextareaProperty;

methodName(event) {
if(isNumber(event){

} else {
// you may the value of last index
bindedTextareaProperty.slice(0, bindedTextareaProperty.length -1);
}
}
```